# How to create a concatenated column if your are getting data from a single column?

Tags: oracle11g, cognos, cognos-10

I have a column called Issue_Status column, it presents the current status of an Issue raised mostly related in Risk Management. I need to to create a new column in both Cognos and/or SQL Server to present the concatenated columns of all previous statuses of an Issue. It goes like this.

Right now, I don't have the Issue_Status_Concatenated.

It goes like this.

```
Issue I.D   Issue Status   

1234        Draft           
1234        Open           
1234        Closed          
5678        Draft           
5678        Pending         
5678        Closed          
5678        Cancelled       
3333        Draft           
3333        Pending         
3333        Pending         
3333        Pending
```

I was thinking of using a running count function (Cognos Function)

```
Issue I.D   Issue Status         Running_Count

1234        Draft                1
1234        Open                 2
1234        Closed               3
5678        Draft                1
5678        Pending              2
5678        Closed               3
5678        Cancelled            4
3333        Draft                1
3333        Pending              2
3333        Pending              3
3333        Pending              4
```

Then combine the results inside a single column using a case function

```
New Concat_Column 1

case when Running_Count = 1 then Issue_status else ' ' end

New Concat_Column 2 

case when Running_Count = 2 then Issue_status else ' ' end

New Concat_Column 3 

case when Running_Count = 3 then Issue_status else ' ' end

New Concat_Column 4

case when Running_Count = 4 then Issue_status else ' ' end
```

Then I plan to create a new data item or a new column by creating  Issue_Status_Concatenated by combining all New concat columns from 1 to

```
New Concat_Column 1 + '|' + New Concat_Column  2 + '|' + New Concat_Column 3 + '|' + New Concat_Column 4
```

I know this is a long process but I know that there could be an easier and logical way to do this? Is there a way to make this simpler?

```
Issue I.D   Issue Status   Issue_Status_Concatenated

    1234        Draft           Draft | Open | Closed
    1234        Open            Draft | Open | Closed
    1234        Closed          Draft | Open | Closed
    5678        Draft           Draft | Open | Closed |Cancelled
    5678        Pending         Draft | Open | Closed |Cancelled
    5678        Closed          Draft | Open | Closed |Cancelled
    5678        Cancelled       Draft | Open | Closed |Cancelled
    3333        Draft           Draft | Pending
    3333        Pending         Draft | Pending
    3333        Pending         Draft | Pending
    3333        Pending         Draft | Pending
```

Comment: Please choose the correct database system.. don't tag mysql, sql-server and oracle11g

Comment: OK done.  I'm not sure which RDBMS we are using currently if it's sql server or Oracle 11g

Comment: What is your actual desired output?  The end of your post doesn't look like what you want.  Do you want a different column for each Issue Status value, or do you really want a single field that delimited with each value for a given issue?

Comment: You're probably not going to want to do this in Cognos.  I think you'll want to create a VIEW in Oracle/SQL Server and then add it to the Framework Manager.

Comment: I'm a reports developer, I dont have access in a sql developer to create a view for this, same thing in Framework Manager to update the query subject. So I'm forced to do this in Cognos report studio

Comment: Well, if you can use an SQL query in Cognos that would work (I forget about those... we prohibit them) but you need to know the RDBMS vendor in order to write the query correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet will help you to get the desird output in oracle. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT ID,
  STAT,
  LISTAGG(STAT,'|') WITHIN GROUP(
ORDER BY STAT) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AGG_STAT
FROM
  (WITH TMP AS
  ( SELECT 1234 id, 'Draft' Stat FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 ID, 'Open' STAT FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 id, 'Completed' Stat FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1100 ID, 'Draft' STAT FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1100 ID, 'Pending' STAT FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1100 ID, 'Completed' STAT FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1100 id, 'Closed' Stat FROM dual
  )
SELECT tmp.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1 DESC) RN FROM tmp
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

if its sql server its

```
SELECT  i.issue_id,
    stuff((
            SELECT DISTINCT ' | ' + issue_status
            FROM issues i1
            WHERE i1.issue_id = i.issue_id for xml path('')),1,3,'')
            FROM issues i
```

if its oracle its probally along the lines of listagg
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server you can use below query to get your result -

```
Create table #IssueLog (
[Issue I.D] int ,
[Issue Status] varchar(10)
)

insert into #IssueLog
select 1234 ,       'Draft'
union all  select 1234,     'Open'           
union all  select 1234,      'Closed'          
union all  select 5678,     'Draft'           
union all  select 5678,      'Pending'         
union all  select 5678,     'Closed'          
union all  select 5678,     'Cancelled'       
union all  select 3333,     'Draft'           
union all  select 3333,     'Pending'         
union all  select 3333,     'Pending'         
union all  select 3333,      'Pending'   


Select Main.[Issue I.D],
       Left(Main.[Issues],Len(Main.[Issues])-1) As [Issues]
From
    (
        Select distinct T2.[Issue I.D] ,
            (
                Select T1.[Issue Status] + '|' AS [text()]
                From #IssueLog T1
                Where T1.[Issue I.D] = T2.[Issue I.D]
                ORDER BY T1.[Issue I.D]
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) [Issues]
        From #IssueLog T2
    ) [Main]
```